# A simple way to redirect http://example.com to http://example.com/mylink with Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect, rewrite

Just starting to try to get the hang of how all the directives and options work under Apache.

I'd like to do a redirect with my one site (only running one site on the server) so that when a request comes in to http:/example.com the server automatically redirects them to a sub-url of http://example.com/mylink.

I have tried putting redirects into the file located in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled to rewrite this, but then the top level domain URL complains it isn't redirecting properly.

I think what I want is a browser redirect, and thought using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ /mylink [L,R]
```

would work, but putting it into an .htaccess file didn't work (it redirected but immediately gave a 500 internal server error.)

Putting it into the file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled gives a configuration error when trying to restart Apache.

I know it's something simple...but what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try a RedirectMatch, instead:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ http://mysite.com/mylink
```

They're often easier when you're after a simple redirect, whereas Rewrites come into their own when you don't want the end user to see the results.

Comment: Worked when I put it into the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sitefile! Thanks!

Comment: +1 for the simple solution.  @Bart If you do try to use mod_rewrite in the future and have similar issues, you'll need to be more forthcoming with the details, such as what's in the error log; 500 errors on untouched URLs don't add up.

Comment: You already touched on the .htaccess not working, @Shane. The only thing in the error log was saying that RewriteEngine is an invalid command in .htaccess. The other attempts showed nothing in the error log.

Comment: @Bart To clarify, it'll work just fine in `.htaccess`, but it expects relative paths when they're used in that context (or `<Directory>`).  I know your issue is solved (and the solution is better than using mod_rewrite, for sure) - just trying to clear up misconceptions on mod_rewrite for if/when you do need to use it, since as you said, you're just starting to get the hang of this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you putting it in the site file?  That should work just fine in the `<VirtualHost>` context, but not in the `.htaccess` file or `<Directory>` context (those expect relative, not absolute, paths).

Then again, they shouldn't blow up the config or cause 500 errors, either - just not redirect.  Should be something interesting in `error.log`.

When you say it redirected *then* 500 errored, the 500 came back on the "new" URL?  Does it 500 when you go directly to it, avoiding the redirect?

Comment: I tried it in the virtualhost block and in an .htaccess file. Yes, the 500 error came from the new url.